# PhantomJS "SSL handshake failed" on HTTPS site, even when using all the flags

Tags: ssl, https, phantomjs, slimerjs

PhantomJS will fail to load many HTTPS urls by default, but you can get many of them to work by adding some command line flags like `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` and `--ssl-protocol=any`. However I'm finding some sites that fail even when these flags are enabled; for example try the following code snippet:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onResourceError = function(e){
  console.log("Page resource failed to load. Reason: "+e.errorString);
}

page.open("https://www.bluehaven.com/pool-remodeling/", function(status){
  console.log("Load status: "+status);
});
```

When I run this script with those two flags enabled, I get the following output:

```
$ phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any lib/test_phantom.js 
Page resource failed to load. Reason: SSL handshake failed
Load status: fail
```

I've googled quite a bit and the discussions around PhantomJS and SSL failures all recommend using the above two command flags, or suggest that this is [due to a bug in PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12440) that isn't likely to get fixed anytime soon.

Does anyone here on SO have different ideas on how I can get PhantomJS to load the above URL (and any other sites where the same HTTPS errors occur)? My plan B is to try out SlimerJS as I understand it doesn't share this SSL error, but that will involve some risk and I'd rather not do it unless absolutely needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program works fine on Ubuntu 14.04 with phantomjs 1.9.0.
Since the server only supports ECDHE ciphers I would assume that you are using an old version of OpenSSL with no support for these ciphers on your system.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm on Mac OSX Yosemite with OpenSSL version 0.9.8zd, but the error also occurs on CentOS with OpenSSL version 1.0.1e. I'll try updating to 1.0.2 and see if that helps. I'm also running latest PhantomJS (2.0.0) which I've learned isn't always smart, in that some bugs occur with the newer versions that didn't show up in earlier versions...

Comment: @Steffen For what it's worth, I get the `SSL handshake failed` error using the same versions of Ubuntu and PhantomJS you mention (Ubuntu 14.04 and PhantomJS 1.9.0). Using same flags as the OP (`--ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any`).

Comment: @supertrue: there are lots of reasons for handshake failures. Please ask a new question with enough details to reproduce your problem instead of adding a comment to a 2 year old post.